# How to send a get request for words with spaces in-between

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

I have this link below ( where the freepeople+top has the + replacing a space)

```
https://poshmark.com/search?query=freepeople+top&type=listings&department=Women
```

I was doing this to query the link :

```
search='https://poshmark.com/search?'

brand="freepeople"

style="top"
# & seperates parameters
queryParameters={'query':[brand,style],'type':'listings','department':'Women'}
response=requests.get(search,params=queryParameters)
```

I'm confused why when I did print(response.text) it appears like it gives me all the html but when I do:

```
MacBook-Air-4:finalproject BCohen$ python3 poshmart.py >/tmp/poshmart.html
MacBook-Air-4:finalproject BCohen$ open /tmp/poshmart.html
```

It doesn't take me to a valid page

I was assuming that maybe I queried the Indexed search ( the + ) wrong but I'm not sure how to properly query it.

Comment: use [urlencode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)

Comment: how do I use it? I went to https://www.urlencoder.org and typed in my link but it gave things back in %

Comment: it also says on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php: The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results.

Comment: that link is PHP

Comment: would you mind elaborating on using the urlencode then?

Comment: the code above is working at my end. what do you mean by "doesn't take me to a valid page"?

Comment: when I run open /tmp/poshmart.html in terminal an empty window opens up, no content shows up

Comment: I would recommend using your code to pre-merge the brand and style into one string with either `+` or `%20` and sending it as one term. `'query':'freepeople+top'`

Comment: @beroe, i first tried that and that didn't work, as in I wrote brand="freepeople"
style="dress"
then 

queryParameters={'query':search+brand,'type':'listings','department':'Women'}
do you mean something different?

Comment: @sphinx, what doe you mean write response.text to one file? if I print it I see it working.

Comment: @Sphinx , actually I can now weirdly see the link but you notice how what shows up isn't correct? Like the tops aren't freepeople brand, there just a mix of brands? so I'm not querying properly

Comment: so you means your `http-get` didn't get the result same as `https://poshmark.com/search?brand=freepeople&style=top&type=listings&department=Women`?

Comment: ugh ok for some reason now it's weirdly all working when i do it my original way ie what @beroe mentioned, but the information that shoes up is like only 5 photos and i know there are a lot more then that

Comment: @Spinx no it didn't it just searched tops that way

Comment: and update, the way I said that worked, doesn't it combined the two words searching freepeopletop without the space so theres like very few listings

Comment: you can open your browser, then access that website, customizes your search, then you will see one url `https://poshmark.com/search?department=Women&brand[]=freepeople&brand[]=Aeropostale&color[]=Blue&_=1522371673839` in the address bar of the browser. You have to customize your parameters to follow that.

Comment: huh? I don't understand what you are trying to point out? also can you rebut back up your suggestions on how to open an html and writing to a new file?

Comment: did you notice **&brand[]=freepeople&brand[]=Aeropostale**?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167843/discussion-between-bob-and-sphinx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'+'.join([brand,style])` to turn that array into a string where the values are joined with a `+`. The result of that would be what you're looking for: `freepeople+top`

```
import requests

search='https://poshmark.com/search?'

brand="freepeople"
style="top"

print('+'.join([brand,style]))

# & seperates parameters
queryParameters={'query':'+'.join([brand,style]),'type':'listings','department':'Women'}
response=requests.get(search,params=queryParameters)

print(response.request.url)
```

and the output is

```
freepeople+top
https://poshmark.com/search?query=freepeople%2Btop&type=listings&department=Women
```

the reason it shows up as `%2B` in the 2nd print is because that is the urlencoded value of `+`

Comment: would you happen to have any idea how I can get all the data that pulls up from this search? since poshmart has a load more, i'm note sure if theres an easy way to get all the data